# Multirow truncated vertical line

Tags: tables, multirow

I am using a multirow in my table for the rightmost column but the vertical line is truncated. How do I fix this?

[image]

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
%\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|cc|cc|cc|cc|r|}
\hline%\noalign{\smallskip}
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:5} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{6:15}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:5} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{6:20}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:20}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\# Params} \\
 &  & SSIM & MSE & SSIM & MSE & SSIM & MSE & SSIM & MSE \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Add a `&` after the last "MSE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has said leandriis, the last vertical rule of the second row is not drawn because your row is not complete since there is not the last cell. Putting `&` at the end of that row creates that cell and draws the rule.

You may also considerer the package `nicematrix`. In the environment `{NiceTabular}` of that package, the vertical rules specified by `|` in the preamble are always drawn. There is not need to add a `|` back in the `\multicolummn` and the rules are drawn even with incomplete rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
%\scriptsize
\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|l|cc|cc|cc|cc|r|}
\hline%\noalign{\smallskip}
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{1:5} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{6:15}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{1:5} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{6:20}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:20}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\# Params} \\
 &  & SSIM & MSE & SSIM & MSE & SSIM & MSE & SSIM & MSE \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
}
\end{center}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]